# Is it possible to give text format hints in google vision api?

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision, icr

I'm trying to detect handwritten dates isolated in images.

[image]

In the cloud vision api, is there a way to give hints about type?

**example: the only text present will be dd/mm/yy, d,m and y being digits**

The only thing I found is language hints in the documentation.

Sometimes I get results that include letters like `O` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to give hints about type but you can filter the output using [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries). I downloaded `detect.py` and `requirements.txt` from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/vision/cloud-client/detect) and modified `detect.py` (in *def detect_text*, after line 283):

```
    response = client.text_detection(image=image)
    texts = response.text_annotations

    #Import regular expressions
    import re

    print('Date:')

    dateStr=texts[0].description
    # Test case for letters replacement
    #dateStr="Z3 OZ/l7"
    #print(dateStr)

    dateStr=dateStr.replace("O","0")    
    dateStr=dateStr.replace("Z","2")    
    dateStr=dateStr.replace("l","1")    

    dateList=re.split(' |;|,|/|\n',dateStr)

    dd=dateList[0]
    mm=dateList[1]
    yy=dateList[2]
    date=dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yy 
    print(date)
    #for text in texts:
        #print('\n"{}"'.format(text.description))
    #print('Hello you!')
        #vertices = (['({},{})'.format(vertex.x, vertex.y)
        #            for vertex in text.bounding_poly.vertices])

        #print('bounds: {}'.format(','.join(vertices)))
    # [END migration_text_detection]
# [END def_detect_text]
```

Then I launched `detect.py` inside the virtual environment using this command line:

```
python detect_dates.py text qAkiq.png
```

And I got this:

```
23/02/17
```

There are few letters that can be mistaken for numbers, so using **str.replace(“letter”,”number”)** should solve the wrong identifications. I added the most common cases for this example.